# Python http server giving error when connected to

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, server

Im getting an error with my server code. It worls till a browser tries to connect to it. I really have no clue what it can be. could any one take a look at it and point me in the right direction?

The error code is

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 57953)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 306, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 332, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 345, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 666, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 400, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 388, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "C:\Ny mapp\serverpy.py", line 44, in do_GET
    self.wfile.write(f.read())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 391, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

The script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from os import curdir, sep
import cgi

PORT_NUMBER = 8080

#This class will handles any incoming request from
#the browser 
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    #Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path=="/":
            self.path="/index.html"

        try:
            #Check the file extension required and
            #set the right mime type

            sendReply = False
            if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                mimetype='text/html'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".jpg"):
                mimetype='image/jpg'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".gif"):
                mimetype='image/gif'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".js"):
                mimetype='application/javascript'
                sendReply = True
            if self.path.endswith(".css"):
                mimetype='text/css'
                sendReply = True

            if sendReply == True:
                #Open the static file requested and send it
                f = open(curdir + sep + self.path) 
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type',mimetype)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
            return

        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

    #Handler for the POST requests
    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path=="/send":
            form = cgi.FieldStorage(
                fp=self.rfile, 
                headers=self.headers,
                environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                         'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
            })

            print("Your name is: %s" % form["your_name"].value)
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write("Thanks %s !" % form["your_name"].value)
            return          


try:
    #Create a web server and define the handler to manage the
    #incoming request
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    print('Started httpserver on port ' , PORT_NUMBER)

    #Wait forever for incoming htto requests
    server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('^C received, shutting down the web server')
    server.socket.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

means that in `socket`, `self._sock.send(b)` only accepts `bytes` objects. So you need to send a bytes encoded string.

Try using the following:

```
def do_GET(self):
    if self.path=="/":
        self.path="/index.html"

    try:
        sendReply = False
        if self.path.endswith(".html"):
            mimetype='text/html'
            sendReply = True
        if self.path.endswith(".jpg"):
            mimetype='image/jpg'
            sendReply = True
        if self.path.endswith(".gif"):
            mimetype='image/gif'
            sendReply = True
        if self.path.endswith(".js"):
            mimetype='application/javascript'
            sendReply = True
        if self.path.endswith(".css"):
            mimetype='text/css'
            sendReply = True

        if sendReply == True:
            #Open the static file requested and send it
            f = open(curdir + sep + self.path) 
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type',mimetype)
            self.end_headers()

            # save the contents
            read = f.read()
            # write the contents as bytes
            self.wfile.write(bytes(read, 'utf-8'))

            f.close()
        return

    except IOError:
        self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)
```

Comment: Tnx for the answer. I changed it to what you wrote but i get a new error instead. TypeError: string argument without an encoding

Comment: never mind got it to work self.wfile.write(bytes(read)) where missing 'UTF-8' so i changed it to self.wfile.write(bytes(read , 'UTF8'))    Tnx for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'rb'`. It's OK with webfont(.ttf;.woff;woff2) etc.

```
f = open(filepath, 'rb')
data = f.read()
self.wfile.write(data)
```